# How to simplify sub functions' arguments in R?

Tags: r, function

Suppose I have a function with sub functions like this format:

```
f<-function(f,a,b,c,d,e) {

    f1<-function(a,b,c,d,e){
    cbind(rnorm(a,mean=b,sd=1),
              rnorm(a,mean=b,sd=c),
            rbinom(a,d,e))
    }
    out<-list()
    for(i in 1:f) {out[[i]]<-f1(a,b,c,d,e)}
    return(out)
}

f(a=10,b=3,c=4,d=3,e=0.5,f=6)
```

## Q1:

How to simplify the arguments for f1?

## Q2:

I use `list()` and `for loop` for the `out`, How to `rbind()` or other better ways to return a single data frame?

## Q3:

How to add `...` in the `f( )` to pass arguments for function `mean`, `rnorm` and `rbinom`?

Comment: Can you please be a bit more vague in your question?

Comment: Explain the argument logic, i.e. how they are supposed to change in the different sub-functions.

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried above to clarify my questions with a working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`func1`, `func2` and `func3` can already access the arguments of `func` directly so it is unnecessary pass the arguments of `func` to each of them. e.g.

```
f <- function(x) {
      g <- function() x*x
      g()
}
f(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's great helpful! Would you have some suggestions for Q2 and Q3?

Comment: `do.call("rbind", replicate(f, f1(a, b, c, d, e), simplify = FALSE))`

Answer (score 0):

use  `as.list(environment())`  eg

```
not.include <- c("a", "f", "vars", "not.include")
vars <- as.list(environment()) 
vars[! names(vars) %in% not.include]
do.call(func1, vars)
```